# Creating a multi record format Text file from SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where I have a temp table in my Stored Proc thats flat but I need to create a multi record format file from it.

Final format of the file should be:

```
ENV
HDR
LIN
LTR
```

Format of my table is:

```
Filename
Sender
Receiver
ProductCode
```

Right now I am building each record format from the table by joining my fields together with pipes into one big ole field in another temp table using a select from the table.  But I am getting

```
ENV
ENV
ENV
HDR
HDR
HDR
LIN
LIN
LIN etc
```

How can I build my big field (I need it this way) in the proper structure of:

```
ENV
HDR
LIN
LTR
ENV
HDR
LIN
LTR
```

Code:

```
Select 'ENV' + '|' + etc AS BigOleField from <table>
UNION ALL
Select 'HDR' + '|' + etc AS BigOleField from <table>
```

Comment: Rows in a resultset have no particular order if the query that generates them does not include an ORDER BY clause. The current answer demonstrates the technique but you will need to adjust it according to the ordering logic you need. In this case you **might** be able to order by the 3 character prefix first but it is likely you will need another column (or columns) to sort correctly within a given prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by` clause like below.

```
Select BigOleField from
(
    Select 'ENV' + '|' + etc AS BigOleField, etc from <table>
    UNION ALL
    Select 'HDR' + '|' + etc AS BigOleField, etc from <table>
)t order by etc, BigOleField
```